# How do you find the root prototype constructor for a constructor in a prototype chain?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I have a chain of constructors using prototype inheritance in JavaScript like so:

```
var Test = function(){};
var Foo = function(){};
var Bar = function(){};
var Baz = function(){};
Bar.prototype = new Baz();
Foo.prototype = new Bar();
Test.prototype = new Foo();
```

I want to write a function getRootConstructor() such that

```
getRootConstructor(Test) === Baz.
```

The goal was that I could do

```
getRootConstructor(Test).prototype = new UniversalBaseConstructor();
```

So I could add functionality to a constructor without breaking the prototype chain. This turns out to be very unintuitive.

Comment: Because of how you've established inheritance, `(new Test()).constructor === Baz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OP, note that:

```
var t = new Test();
t.constructor == Test; // false
t.constructor == Baz;  // true
```

So the base constructor is given by `t.constructor`.

However, it is very common to re–set ("fix") the constructor property when building inheritance like that so that each prototype's *constructor* property points to the right constructor:

```
var Test = function(){};
var Foo = function(){};
var Bar = function(){};
var Baz = function(){};

Bar.prototype = new Baz();
Bar.prototype.consructor = Bar;

Foo.prototype = new Bar();
Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo;

Test.prototype = new Foo();
Test.prototype.constructor = Test;
```

which means that Brad's *getRootConstructor* function will not work as `Constructor.prototype.constructor` always points to the "real" constructor and

```
getRootConstructor(Test) === Test;
```

In this case it is also common to add a `_super` (or similar named) property to each prototype that points to the prototype's constructor, so the base constructor could be found that way.

Note that if Brad's function really worked, it would always return the built–in Function object, as it is the base constructor for all functions.

Comment: You're right about class vs. constructor, so I edited the question. My answer does break if you re-set prototype.constructor, however it works otherwise.

Comment: The *prototype* property of a *prototype* object is established when its associated constructor function is created. Because you replace that *prototype* object with an instance from a particular constructor and do not assign a constructor property, every instance created from any constructor in the chain will inherit the "base" prototype's constructor, so `anyInstance.constructor` and `anyConstructor.prototype.constructor` will reference the base constructor. So there is no need for a *getRootConstructor* function. :-)

Comment: If you want to remove the references to classes from this, I'll accept it as the answer

Comment: Since you removed classes from the OP… :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't set the prototype of a function, they have a circular reference such that F.prototype.constructor === F. The function you want, then, is:

```
function getRootConstructor(T){
 return T.prototype.constructor === T ? T : getRootConstructor(T.prototype.constructor);
}
```

Comment: Until someone messes with the (public, mutable) *constructor*…